# How can we get powerautomate swagger api and orchester

Tags: c#, power-automate, rpa

In Uipath we have orchestrator we can run process and see jobs and logs robot etc

How can we see this in power automate what is process.

Is there any swagger api details for power automate.

I tried to find some reference but not got correct one